# how to start a function on eventlistener

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to start a countdown function with an event listener because at the moment it starts automatically.

I found this code somewhere on the net and want to adjust it to my needs but I need some help.

I guess `setInterval` must be to blame. I guess it runs the function every second, right?

But I want it to start when I press the button, so I put the `setInterval` inside the `updateCountdown` body but weird things started to happen (that the clock started to work irregularly)

```
const startingMinutes = 25;
let time = startingMinutes * 60;
const startBtn = document.querySelector("#start-btn");

startBtn.addEventListener("click", updateCountdown);

const countdownEl = document.querySelector("#countdown");

function updateCountdown() {
  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let seconds = time % 60;
  seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
  countdownEl.innerHTML = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  time--;
}

setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);
```

```
<div id="display-container">
  <div id="display-timer">
    <p id="countdown">25:00</p>
  </div>
  <p id="display-logo">Focus</p>
</div>
<div id="buttons-container">
  <button id="reset-btn">
    <i class="fas fa-undo-alt"></i></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <button id="start-btn"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></ion- icon></button>
  <button id="pause-btn"><i class="fas fa-pause"></i></ion-icon></button>
</div>
```

Comment: _"But I want it to start when I press the button"_ - Then remove the `setInterval()` call at the end. _"so I put the setInterval inside the updateCountdown body but weird things started to happen"_ - The call is not in the event handler. And if you want help with that _"weird behavior"_ you have to add a [mcve] or at least a description of that _"weird behavior"_

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) + [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to start the countdown only when the user clicks the button. In that case, use `addEventListener` to add a function that calls `setInterval`, passing to that the function you actually want repeated. So it will look like this:

```
const startingMinutes = 25;
let time = startingMinutes * 60;
const startBtn = document.querySelector("#start-btn");

startBtn.addEventListener("click", startCountdown);

const countdownEl = document.querySelector("#countdown");

function updateCountdown() {
  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let seconds = time % 60;
  seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
  countdownEl.innerHTML = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  time--;
}

function startCountdown() {
  setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);
}
```

I'll leave it to you to sort out more subtle details like what should happen if the user clicks the button a second time.

Comment: How is this different to OPs script? When `startBtn` is clicked the attached event handler executes `updateCountdown()` (`startBtn.addEventListener("click", updateCountdown)`) which, according to OP although not in the question, then calls `setInterval()` (_"so I put the setInterval inside the updateCountdown"_).

Comment: It's completely different. In my version, nothing will happen till the user clicks, and then updateCountdown will be executed every second - which is what I think the OP wants. The OP's version was setting up the interval unconditionally on page load, and then executing updateCountdown itself additionally on each click.

Comment: startBtn.addEventListener("click", startCountdown, { once: true });  right? But why? Does each click change the interval by 1s?

Comment: _"OP's version was setting up the interval unconditionally on page load"_ - We don't know what the actual script of OP is (script and description don't match). The only difference to your version is the missing `setInterval()` at the end, and an additional `startCountdown()`. OPs description sounds like a self-calling `updateCountdown()`. _"and then executing updateCountdown itself additionally on each click"_ - Your script also starts a new interval on each click.

Comment: @TomDev - yes, that's the simple way to do it, assuming you don't want subsequent clicks to do anything. It's needed because with the code I've shown, each click starts `updateCountdown` running every second, so two clicks will have it running twice a second (probably not evenly, it depends exactly when the clicks happened), a third click would have it happening 3 times a second, and so on.

Comment: @Andreas you're right that my version doesn't handle repeated clicks well, which I acknowledged in the answer. But we do know what the OP's code was, it's in the question. They have `setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);` at the top level of the script - therefore executed on page load. The countdown would automatically run, with no click required - clearly not what they wanted. I've fixed that. Also the OP code was having the event handler be `updateCountdown` which merely decrements once - I've made it so that the event handler is what sets up the interval to call that function once a second.

Comment: Robin Zigmond - But if I want to use a pause button to clearInterval, I won't be able to resume the countdown. What then? Is there any other EASY way to solve that?

Comment: @TomDev this sounds like a separate question, not something which should be discussed in comments. But in short, you could use a variable to keep track of whether the countdown is running or not, and not start it if it's already running.